# How to find students between two date columns within the last 30 days

Tags: sql-server

I am needing to get the students that canceled their class within the last 30 days of the class report date for the last year.  The following query works in Access and I can make the first three lines of the where clause work in SQL Sever with cast, but not the forth line.  I have tried multiple different ways but no luck.

```
`SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE   (([TABLE1].ClsReportDate)<=Now() And
(([TABLE1].ClsReportDate)>=Now()-365) AND
(([TABLE1].LastUpdateDate)<=[Table1].ClsReportDate) And
(([TABLE1].LastUpdateDate)>=[TABLE1].ClsReportDate)-30)
ORDER BY [TABLE1].LastUpdateDate;`
```

Comment: If you are adding or subtracting time ranges on dates, I strongly recommend using `DATEADD` in T-SQL. Don't treat dates as numerical values; they aren't numerical values.

Comment: in sql-server now() would be GetDate() and to subtract 365 from a date it should be dateadd(day, -365, ClsReportDate). If your goal is to subtract a year then use dateadd(year, -1, ClsReportDate)

Comment: Access and t-sql are different dialects of sql. Date math is very different. The NOW function does not exist in sql server. Those are the two big differences from the code you posted.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got it with a little help from GuidoG.                                                   SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE  cast(([TABLE1].ClsReportDate) as date) <= cast(getdate() as date) And
 cast(([TABLE1].ClsReportDate) as date) >= cast(getdate()-365 as date) AND
 (([TABLE1].LastUpdateDate)<=[TABLE1].[ClsReportDate]) And
 (([TABLE1].LastUpdateDate)>= dateadd(day, -30, [TABLE1].[ClsReportDate])) AND
ORDER BY [TABLE1].[LastUpdateDate];